# Non-JS trigger click event on <input type=checkbox> when <button type=submit> clicked

Tags: html, form-submit, forms

I have a form with a `<button type="submit">` and I'm looking for a non-JS way to trigger the click event on a hidden/display:none'd `<input type="checkbox">` when that button is clicked.

My first thought was something like

```
<form>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="all" style="display:none;"/>
    <button type="submit">I want everything</button>
  <label>
  ... checkboxes ...
  ... submit selected items ...
</form>
```

But as you can see in the JSFiddle below, when you click the button, the button click event fires then the label click happens, but the input click doesn't happen.

JS Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/yqat20xp/42/

I'm wondering if there's a non-JS way to do this. Basically what I want is for the `<input type="checkbox">` to be unchecked, but if that `<button type="submit">` is clicked I want the form data to register that the checkbox was checked.

The reasoning behind this is I have a form with multiple checkboxes, an "I want everything!" button that submits, and a regular submit button for users that want to check some but not all of the checkboxes.

On the backend, I want to see that the user submitted the "I want everything" button, or that they selected some of the options and clicked the regular "submit selected" button. The backend is sealed off, so I have to pass in a checked `<input type="checkbox">`. Additionally, I could pass in an `<input type="radio">` indicating which button was pressed.

Is this possible to do without JS?

Answer (score 0):

Simplify your problem:

You just want to know which button was clicked. So just assign different values to those buttons.

```
<button type="submit" name="btn_submit" value="all">i want everything</button>
<button type="submit" name="btn_submit" value="some">only checked</button>
```

In your server script you can now check which button was clicked

Comment: I wish I could! Unfortunately I'm locked into the current implementation which only registers checkboxes and radio buttons :/